# Stream subscription is not listening to changes in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, bloc, flutter-bloc

I m trying to fetch `Firestore` documents in **BLoC** pattern. There are two events, one fetches all the documents, the other fetches documents based on a query. Here is the code for the two events:

```
  Stream<JobFeedState> _mapFetchAllJobPostsToState(
      FetchAllJobPosts event) async* {
    yield LoadingJobPosts();
    try {
      _jobsSubscription?.cancel();
      _jobsSubscription = _jobsRepository.getAllTheJobsPosted().listen((jobs) {
        add(JobPostsRefreshed(jobs: jobs));
      });
    } catch (e) {
      yield Error(message: e.toString());
    }
  }

  Stream<JobFeedState> _mapFetchJobPostsForLocation(
      FetchJobPostsForLocation event) async* {
    yield LoadingJobPosts();
    try {
      _jobsSubscription?.cancel();
      _jobsInLocationsubscription?.cancel();
      _jobsInLocationsubscription =
          _jobsRepository.getJobsInALocation(event.location.country).listen((jobs) {
        add(JobPostsRefreshed(jobs: jobs));
      });
    } catch (e) {
      yield Error(message: e.toString());
    }
  }
```

`_mapFetchAllJobPostsToState()` is working as expected. But the other one, `_mapFetchJobPostsForLocation()` fetches data first time, but then it doesn't show the changes in stream. Here is the function that fetches data based on a query :

```
  // getJobsInALocation()
  Stream<List<JobPostDocumentModel>> getJobsInALocation(String location) {
    var collectionGroup =
        Firestore.instance.collectionGroup(AppStringConstants.posts);
    return collectionGroup
        .where(AppStringConstants.country, isEqualTo: location)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents.map((docSnapshot) {
        DocumentReference documentReference = docSnapshot.reference;
        JobPostModel jobPostModel = JobPostModel.fromSnapshot(docSnapshot);
        JobPostDocumentModel jobPostDocumentModel = JobPostDocumentModel(
          documentReference: documentReference,
          jobPostModel: jobPostModel,
        );
        return jobPostDocumentModel;
      }).toList();
    });
  }
```

Whats wrong here?

Comment: *"_mapFetchJobPostsForLocation() fetches data first time, but then it doesn't show the changes in stream"* - what does it mean? tried to `print(jobs)` before calling `add(JobPostsRefreshed(jobs: jobs));`?

Comment: @pskink It means , I get expected result when that function is called first time. If there is any change in data, the changes should be visible in UI. But it is not. Infact the streamsubscription is not listening to the changes.

Comment: `print(jobs)` first time prints **[Instance of 'JobPostDocumentModel']**. Then it doesn't print anything when the data changes.

Comment: so where are you calling it? are you sure that you dont call `_jobsInLocationsubscription?.cancel();` somewhere?

Comment: If I use `_jobsRepository.getAllTheJobsPosted()`, I get expected result. Thats why I think problem is in `getJobsInALocation()` function.

Comment: @pskink I dont call `_jobsInLocationsubscription?.cancel();`  anywhere else.

Comment: *" I get expected result when that function is called first time"* - so where and how many times do you call that function? i mean `_mapFetchJobPostsForLocation`

Comment: Actually I have two events for those two functions. In **BLoC** class there is another `StreamSubscription` for checking GPS. If GPS is on, an event calls `_mapFetchJobPostsForLocation`. If GPS is off, another event calls the other function.